Panel data from Excel transformation
I have data from the WIND terminal with the data structured in rows (even time series information)
For example:
Ticker Company Name NetProfitGrowth2009 NetProfitGrowth2010

I believe in order to estimate a time series regression I need to transform the data into the panel data so that its structure is
Ticker Company Year Net Profit Growth (so that for example for 15 years 15 different rows correspond to the same company)
How do I do it quickly since doing it like transposing and pasting/copying would take  hours given that I have 347 companies and 15 years? The data is in Excel. What would be your suggestions?

Welcome to StackOverflow!  Are you familiar with R? A famous group of package ( grouped in tidyverse) include the package  readxl and the function read_excel() . Also, pivot_longer() from the pacakge tidyr is meant to use the year (ex. in NetProfitGrowth as a value of a variable year. I don't know about WIND.

In Stata, this calls for reshape long, perhaps
reshape long NetProfitGrowth, i(Ticker Company) j(Year)


In R you can use this:
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
your_data_frame %>% 
  pivot_longer(NetProfitGrowth2009:NetProfitGrowth2010, names_to = "Year", values_to = "Profit_Growth") %>% 
  mutate(Year = sub("\\D+", "", Year) %>% as.integer)

